# Библиографическая карточка с использованием классов

Tags: классы, delphi-7

Здраствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, написать программу библиографическая карточка с использованием классов на `delphi`. На `С++` написал, а вот делфи уже подзабыл что-то.
Программа должна добавлять информацию о книге (автор, название, год издания, издательство и число страниц) в файл и выполнять поиск по названию книги или имени автора.

Comment: Алгоритм дальнейших действий:

1) Читаем правила форума. 

2) Понимаем, что про готовые решения спрашивают не тут.

3) Задаём вопрос по конкретной проблеме (напримере: как вызвать WinAPI функцию из Delphi)

4) Радуемся ответам

Comment: @Vovito, постарайтесь подбирать более информативные заголовки к Вашим вопросам.

Comment: >На С++ написал, а вот делфи уже подзабыл что-то

а вы точно на С++ сами написали? Как-то слабо верится, что сумев написать программу на плюсах, Delphi вы не осилили

Comment: давно дэлфи не юзал... пересеть трудновато... вспоминать надо